# Is it possible to group by full-stop in this XML?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'd like to impose some structure on the following XML:

```
<phr>ΦP
    <i>το αθάνατο</i> ~.
    <i>ήπιε το αμίλητο</i> ~.
    <i>πίνω</i> ~ <i>στο όνομα κάποιου</i>, τον σέβομαι, τον εκτιμώ, αναγνωρίζοντας τα όσα του οφείλω.
    <i>λέω το</i> ~ <i>νεράκι</i>, για μεγάλη έλλειψη νερού.
</phr>
```

by grouping the contents of  with the full-stop as a separator, as in:

```
<phr>
    <group>ΦP <i>το αθάνατο</i> ~.</group>
    <group>  <i>ήπιε το αμίλητο</i> ~.</group>
    <group>  <i>πίνω</i> ~ <i>στο όνομα κάποιου</i>, τον σέβομαι, τον εκτιμώ, αναγνωρίζοντας τα όσα <group>του οφείλω.</group>
    <group><i>λέω το</i> ~ <i>νεράκι</i>, για μεγάλη έλλειψη νερού.</group>
</phr>
```

Can anyone recommend some XSLT (2.0) for achieving this?  I've tried for-each-group group-by 'text()[matches(.,'.')]', but that doesn't yield the desired result.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `text()[contains(.,'.')]`. The `matches()` function does regex, if you want to use it you'd need to eacape the `.` like this  `\.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet should do what you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="phr">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="text()[contains(.,'.')]">
        <group>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```